# Adding organizational unit to DirectoryEmulator results in "Target class [config] does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I am trying to test functionality in my Laravel application. One of my tests should test if only users which are part of a specific group can login through LDAP. To test the functionality, I am using `DirectoryEmulator`.

So, my idea was like this:

- Create a `DirectoryEmulator`
- create an organizational unit
- create a group which should be part of the organizational unit
- create a user
- add this user to the group and login

But when I try to create an organizational unit I get the error message during the tests: `Target class [config] does not exist.`

```
    public function test_create_admin_user_and_login()
    {
        $sqlite_ldap_emulator_file = storage_path('ldap_test_database.sqlite');

        $fake = DirectoryEmulator::setup('default', ['database' => $sqlite_ldap_emulator_file]);

        // this line produces the error message: Target class [config] does not exist.
        $ou = OrganizationalUnit::create([
            'ou' => 'Service Groups'
        ]);

// ...

    }
```

What I am missing here?

According to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/test-error-only-when-running-suite-target-class-config-does-not-exist the framework is not booted. But the test class is extended from `Tests\TestCase`, so this should be ok:

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{
// ...
}
```

Also the `setUp()` function for the test class looks ok:

```
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withoutMiddleware(\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class);
    }
```

Also, according to https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v3/testing/#emulated-queries in the given example function `test_index_works` first, the function `DirectoryEmulator::setup` and then two lines later, an `OrganizationalUnit` is created like in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

One way to get the tests running is to enable `processIsolation` in `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         processIsolation="true"
>
...
</phpunit>
```

Alternatively one can run `php artisan run --process-isolation`.

**Solution 2**

Another solution I found is to add the `tearDown()` function to the test class:

```
protected function tearDown(): void
{
    DirectoryEmulator::tearDown();

    parent::tearDown();
}
```